# how to play flash(.flv) video using video.js in chrome

Tags: flash, html5-video, video.js

I am using `video.js` to play flash(.flv) video. But when I press play button it does not play video?
I have used the `"techorder:"["flash","html"]`. But it made no difference.
Is there any plugin to for flash video in `videojs`? How can I play .flv video in `video.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

video.js can play FLV in the Flash tech.

If you're self-hosting video.js rather than using the CDN, make sure the path to your swf is correct, e.g.

```
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://example.com/path/to/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

Make sure to use the correct `video/x-flv` mime type in the source tag:

```
<source src="http://example.com/video.flv" type='video/x-flv'>
```

The server hosting the FLV must also return the correct mime type in the 'Content-Type` header.

Example: http://output.jsbin.com/juvuca

Comment: its not working in my local file. jsbin output example is working fine.Please guide me how to solve this problem for local file

Comment: Define local file. Modified copy of video.js, flv served from file://, something else? Code for or a link to minimal test case would help.

Comment: its working fine on localhost but not working on c9.io please help how to solve this problem. I am using node js.

Comment: I have tried this but not working. When compared my page with the given example, I have noticed that video tag got replaced with object tag (in example page), but its not happening in my case. Can any one help me to understood what I am missing!!

Comment: It's very weird that it can play flv when opening a remote html file. After I saved the remote html and opened it locally, there was only a giant play button, nothing else happened.  [File on jsbin](http://output.jsbin.com/hihodosijo).

Comment: FLV video not playing locally, you can check out this: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1461

Comment: The [example in this answer](http://output.jsbin.com/juvuca) shows "no compatible source was found for this video".

Answer (score 8):

You should use flv.js, an HTML5 FLV Player written in pure JavaScript. No Flash is required.

https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js

You can make a source handler to integrate `flv.js` with `video.js`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the plugin here -`https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins` 
Not sure if this will work.

If not try this as well -`http://jsfiddle.net/N8Zs5/18/`

Regards,
Shashi

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.

- Pure html5 technical. You can use [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) as user @xqq suggest. You may need [videojs-flvjs](https://github.com/mister-ben/videojs-flvjs) to integrate [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) with [video.js](http://videojs.com) together.
- Flash technical. You have to install [videojs-flash](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-flash) to work with `video.js`.

You can choose one of them to support playing flv video. Also, you can use both of them and specify their order by `techOrder` option.

```
data-setup='{"techOrder":["html5", "flvjs", "flash"]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

this project may help you, https://github.com/mister-ben/videojs-flvjs

```
<!-- Video.js -->
<link href="//path/to/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//path/to/video.min.js"></script>
<!-- flv.js -->
<script src="//path/to/flv.min.js"></script>
<!-- videojs-flvjs -->
<script src="//path/to/videojs-flvjs.min.js"></script>
<video id="videojs-flvjs-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
  <source src="movie.flv" type='video/x-flv'>
</video>
<script>
  // For v5 the tech must be added to the tech order.
  // For v6 this is not needed.
  videojs('videojs-flvjs-player', {
    techOrder: ['html5', 'flvjs'],
    flvjs: {
      mediaDataSource: {
        isLive: true,
        cors: true,
        withCredentials: false,
      },
      // config: {},
    },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made refactor of videojs-flvjs for compitable with es6 module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-flvjs-es6

Comment: As of March 2022, this is the only working solution to my Vue-based project. It's easy to integrate with video.js. Nice one! @xlaoyu.Lee